# Timestamp generated by two threads

Tags: multithreading, timestamp

I have two thread in my code. One thread is a generator which creates messages. A timestamp is generated before a message is transmitted. The other thread is a receiver which accepts replies from multiple clients. A timestamp is created for each reply. Two threads are running at the same time.

I find the timestamp generated by the receivers is earlier than the timestamp generated by the generator. The correct order should be the timestamp for the receiver is later than the timestamp for the generator.

If I give a high priority for the generator thread, this problem does not occcur. But this can also slow down the performance.

Is there other way to guarantee the correct order and less effection on the performance? Thanks.

Comment: This type of problem is usually quite dependent on the programming language and OS.  What programming language are you working in and under what OS?

Comment: I use Java and running on Windows XP

Comment: If the producer timestamp is stored in the messages, the producer and consumer timestamps generated in the same way and both times read/displayed at the consumer, the only way I can see this happening is if time is going backwards.   Are you doing any neutrino experiments?

Comment: @MartinJames - this can happen if the messages are enqueued and dequeued in time period that is smaller than the resolution of the clock or by the JVM optimizer generating the timestamp and caching it earlier than the point of declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment thread in the question, this is likely the effect of the optimizer.  This is really a problem with the design more than anything else - it assumes that the clocks between the producer and consumer are shared or tightly synchronized.  This assumption seems reasonable until you need to distribute the processing between more than one computer.

Clocks are rarely (if ever) tightly synchronized between different computers.  The common algorithm for synchronizing computers is the [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).  You can achieve very close to millisecond synchronization on the local area network but even that is difficult.

There are two solutions to this problem that come to mind.  The first is to have the producer's timestamp is passed through the client and into the receiver.  If the receiver receives a timestamp that is earlier than it's notion of the *current time*, then it simply resets the timestamp to the current time.  This type of normalization will allow assumptions  about time being a monotonically increasing sequence continue to hold.

The other solution is to disable optimization and hope that the problem goes away.  As you might expect, your mileage may vary considerably with this solution.

Depending on the problem that you are trying to solve you may be able to provide your own synchronized *clock* between the different threads.  Use an atomically incrementing number instead of the *wall time*.  `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` or one of its relatives can be used to provide a single number that is incremented every time that a message is generated.  This allows the producer and receiver to have a shared value to use as a clock of sorts.

In any case, clocks are really hard to use correctly especially for synchronization purposes.  If you can find some way to remove assumptions about time from distributed systems, your architectures and solutions will be more resilient and more deterministic.